# Mapping a new column header to newly added html table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to accomplish is to allow the user to generate a table on a page, allow user to create new column(s), and for the column names to show up, and be mapped to, the data in the same column.

Currently, I am able to build the table and I have a generated table that maps its column headers to a select box. I have a refresh button on this page, that when clicked, refreshes the select box headers (in case a user creates a new column).

When I refresh the select box, the correct headers drop down, but the data that should be selected along with them are not mapped (I can see this with my console.log statements) This only happens when I create a column.. the column is appended to the table, but when I do something like

```
$('#dropHeader').change( function() {
    firstArray = [];
    console.log('First Select Box Changed');
    var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
    currentValue1 = ($(this).val());
    console.log(currentValue1);
    var elem1 = $("#theTable td:contains("+ currentValue1 +")");
    console.log(elem1);
    var index1 = elem1.index('#theTable td');
    console.log(index1);
    index1+=1;
    $("#theTable tr td:nth-child("+ index1 +")").each(function () {
        firstArray.push($(this).text());
    }); 
    firstArray.shift();

});
```

This works only for columns that are originally a part of the table.

Something that might help is that the console.log jQuery selector statements that I documented:

Normal selector statement:

```
[td,prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#theTable td:contains(Header 2)"]
```

Column Added selector statement:

```
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#theTable td:contains(New Column↵)"]
```

I've looked at this one for a while, and the I believe the issue lies within the jQuery selector statement. One thing I notice is the return signal at the end of the jQuery selector statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: *"mapped to data in same column"* ... not clear what source of data is or if data already exists for new columns.  A sandbox environment demo would really help

Comment: Could it be JQuery function on future elements (not present at the moment of registering)? It works as long as the inserted element is inside the element that bound the event.

Comment: It would help a lot if you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)